# Cocos2d application freeze when loading sound

Tags: animation, audio, cocos2d-iphone

Load sound after 3 seconds delay. When loading this sound, animations that happening in the update function stuck for a moment(mili seconds)

```
- (void) onEnter
{
[super onEnter];
[self schedule:@selector(update:)];
[self performSelector:@selector(playSong) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

}

-(void)playSong{

 soundEffectID=[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"song.mp3"];
}
```

Sound file is only 400kb.

Comment: "only" is relative, loading 400 KB still takes a little time, more so if it's a compressed mp3. Use .wav or .caf or use playBackgroundMusic to play (stream) mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `preloadEffect` Before playing it, It will avoid the jerk in the animation and frame rate.

Example : `[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"bell.wav"];`